# CloudBees Jenkins cc.xml API

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to use a program (CCMenu in my case) to get Jenkins build statuses. Jenkins has CruiseControl API for it: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+Jenkins , but I cannot use it with my Cloudbees CI Jenkins due to authentication issue.

In fact, https://USER.ci.cloudbees.com/cc.xml works, but only after I have logged in to my account. Otherwise the URL redirects to HTML-based authentication, so this certainly does not work with any "real" URL fetch tool. At least the CCMenu and probably other tools also would work if HTTP Basic authentication would be supported for cc.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to use Cloudbees with CCMenu on OSX. I just had to check the uses authentication checkbox and put in full email address and password in CCMenu but it fetched everything.